# Is it possible to insert an IF clause inside of a WHERE clause in a SELECT?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to PL/SQL.
I have a PL/SQL Stored Procedure which retrieves data from a table.
There are 2 optional parameters which can be null. If they're not null they should be part of the WHERE clause.

This is the SELECT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PN.PART_NUMBER, PN.SHORT_CODE, DES.DESCRIPTION
FROM           MAS_PART              PN
LEFT JOIN      CF_DESCRIPTION        DES  
ON PN.LOCAL_DESCRIPTION_ID = DES.DESCRIPTION_ID              
WHERE PN.PART_CODE = 'M'
AND PN.PART_TYPE_ID = IN_PART_TYPE_ID
AND PN.PART_GROUP_ID = IN_PART_GROUP_ID
ORDER BY PN.PART_NUMBER;
```

The two variables are **IN_PART_TYPE_ID** and **IN_PART_GROUP_ID**. Is there any way to evaluate the WHERE clauses regarding these two variables only when they're NOT NULL? Or the only way is to repeat the SELECT 3 times using IF clauses and changing the WHERE clauses?

Comment: `where ( col = param or param is null) and ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OR operatior will help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PN.PART_NUMBER, PN.SHORT_CODE, DES.DESCRIPTION
FROM           MAS_PART              PN
LEFT JOIN      CF_DESCRIPTION        DES  
ON PN.LOCAL_DESCRIPTION_ID = DES.DESCRIPTION_ID              
WHERE PN.PART_CODE = 'M'
AND (PN.PART_TYPE_ID = IN_PART_TYPE_ID or IN_PART_TYPE_ID is null)
AND (PN.PART_GROUP_ID = IN_PART_GROUP_ID or IN_PART_GROUP_ID is null)
ORDER BY PN.PART_NUMBER;
```

Another option is to use NVL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PN.PART_NUMBER, PN.SHORT_CODE, DES.DESCRIPTION
FROM           MAS_PART              PN
LEFT JOIN      CF_DESCRIPTION        DES  
ON PN.LOCAL_DESCRIPTION_ID = DES.DESCRIPTION_ID              
WHERE PN.PART_CODE = 'M'
AND PN.PART_TYPE_ID = NVL(IN_PART_TYPE_ID, PN.PART_TYPE_ID)
AND PN.PART_GROUP_ID = NVL(IN_PART_GROUP_ID, PN.PART_GROUP_ID)
ORDER BY PN.PART_NUMBER;
```

But it will work only if PN.PART_TYPE_ID and PN.PART_GROUP_ID is not null

Comment: You can extend it to:
`AND nvl(PN.PART_TYPE_ID,'X#z') = NVL(IN_PART_TYPE_ID, nvl(PN.PART_TYPE_ID,'X#z'))` to cover nulls. Where `X#z` is some string that can't exist in column.

Comment: but if you have an index on a column, it would be considered for `(column=some_expression)`, but not for `(some_function(column)=some_expression)`

Comment: Using `NVL` will not give the same answer as the first query if the value in the table is `NULL`. Try `SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NVL( NULL, NULL ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM DUAL` and compare it with `SELECT CASE WHEN ( NULL = NULL OR NULL IS NULL ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM DUAL`.

Comment: **WHY** would anyone ever want to use `nvl` here? What is wrong with `OR` in the condition?

Comment: @mathguy - just done a quick test. Nulls passed in as parameter works AND having nulls in the table columns works. The solution involving NVL is irrelevant and doesn't work for the full range of possible values.